# 3 pole 4 wire grounding 3 phase 250 volts

Tags: electrical, receptacle

So I’m trying to add a new circuit breaker for a plug because there are multiple outlets on this circuit and when everything is being used the breaker trips

The outlet is a 125/250v 4 wire 3 pole 3 phase grounded outlet that powers up a meat cutting saw.

My question is that do I need 3 breakers to power up this plug or would I be fine with just 2 breakers. Because from what I understand I can get 210 volts phase to phase so I don’t see why I’d need all 4 wires. I think that I’d only need 2 hots and a ground and I should be fine. That would mean that I’d only occupy 3 out of the 4 screws on the plug.

Thank you

Comment: Are you rewiring this onto a dedicated circuit, or...?

Comment: Shoot us a photo of the nameplate on the motor.

Comment: What flavor of 3-phase? That term alone is not defining..

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a big problem when a three phase motor loses a phase, the remaining phases will be overloaded trying to make up the slack.  There are even monitors / relays to prevent running a motor with a phase lost.  So you definitely wouldn't want to try to run the motor with a missing phase.